# How to dynamically name an array to .map on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const linesImages = metrosLines.map((line, i) => {
```

Hello, I need to dynamically rename the name of the array above "metrosLines" to transport + 'Lines'.map((line, i) =>

Transport (this.props.transport destructured) is a prop that is equal to this.state.selectValue in a parent component,

To sum up, if transport === "rers", I need to do "rerLines.map",
If transport === "metros", I need to do "metrosLines.map", and if transport === "tramways" I need to do "tramwaysLines.map",

Does someone know how can I dynamically name the array where I map on?

Thank you

```
const { transport, data } = this.props;
const transportImage = require(`../../../images/${transport}/${transport}.svg`);

const metrosLines = ['1', '2', '3', '3bis', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7bis', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'];
const rersLines = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const tramwaysLines = ['1', '2', '3a', '3b', '5', '6', '7', '8'];


const linesImages = metrosLines.map((line, i) => {
    const importLineImage =  require(`../../../images/${transport}/${line}.svg`);
    return <Media object data-src="holder.js/64x64" src={ importLineImage } alt="Logo ligne métro RATP" key={i} />;
});
```

Comment: JavaScript does not allow for that generally, though you can create object property names dynamically. If you put your arrays in an object, then it's easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You can convert metrosLines,rersLines and tramwaysLines to an object with these as key like

```
const lines = { 
    metrosLines : ['1', '2', '3', '3bis', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7bis', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
    rersLines : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    tramwaysLines : ['1', '2', '3a', '3b', '5', '6', '7', '8']
}
```

then you can you it like

```
lines[`${transport}Lines`].map()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
const lines = {
    metrosLines,
    rersLines,
    tramwaysLines
}
```

and then access the lines like:

```
lines[transport + "Lines"].map()
```

Comment: thank you for helping me but it tells me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: but whats the value of "transport" ?  Also you need to make sure that the lines have values, if metroLines is undefined then you'll get that error

Comment: the answer by @Abhay Sehgal below worked, the value of transport is either "metros" or "rers" or "tramways"

Answer (score 1):

I need to caution you on the answer before giving it to you. If you are doing it exactly as you put it there, and you intend to dynamically look things up without keeping an associative map or `switch`, `eval()` is your only alternative. You need to be aware of this, as you will need to make sure `transport` does not contain anything nasty.

```js
const metrosLines = ['1', '2', '3', '3bis', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7bis', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'];
const rersLines = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const tramwaysLines = ['1', '2', '3a', '3b', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
var transport = 'metros';

console.log(eval(transport+"Lines"));
```

If you are open to changing your structure a bit, however, you can work with this:

```js
const lines = {
  metros: ['1', '2', '3', '3bis', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7bis', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
  rers: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  tramways: ['1', '2', '3a', '3b', '5', '6', '7', '8']
 }
 
 var transport = "rers";
 
 console.log(lines[transport]);
```

This removes the need for `eval` while preserving most of the freedom you had in your code.